# Measure values by measure by date in Rows

Tags: ssas, mdx

I Am trying to receive all the measures by date from a cube, on a row based result.

Something like this:

```
╔═════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Measure ║ Date ║ Value ║
╠═════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  Meas1  ║   D1 ║     3 ║
║  Meas1  ║   D2 ║     8 ║
║  Meas1  ║   D3 ║     9 ║
║  Meas2  ║   D1 ║     7 ║
║  Meas2  ║   D2 ║     4 ║
╚══...════╩═══..═╩═══...═╝
```

What I have right now is:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Sales].[Source].[Environment] as "Development"
select 
[Sales].[Source].[Environment] ON COLUMNS,
[Measures].AllMembers * [Date].[Date].[Date] ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

This returns all the Measures for all the dates in the date dimension.
But how do I add the values here?

Comment: The solution i have now is based on a Stackoverflow question here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161390/ssas-show-measures-on-rows?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add any other dimension from your Cube that has an [All] Member.

```
SELECT 
    [YourOtherDimension].[YourAttributeWithanALLMEMBER].[All] ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
    [Measures].AllMembers * 
    [Date].[Date].[Date] ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!